# Google Tag Manager Container not found ios swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, google-tag-manager

I am currently trying to include Google Tag Manager in my iOS application (using Xcode 8 and Swift 3) but XCode somehow cannot find the container. I followed the steps written in the official Google Document [here](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/ios/v3/swift).

The error I got was:

> GoogleTagManager warning: Cannot find binary resource file
>   'GTM-xxxxJ'.
>
> GoogleTagManager warning: Cannot find resource file
>   'GTM-xxxxJ.plist'.
>
> GoogleTagManager warning: Cannot find resource file 'GTM-xxxxJ.json'.
>
> GoogleTagManager error: No default container found; creating an empty
>   container.

I have published the container and am running the new version of the it, yet seem to get the above error.

Comment: It would be great if you could add what you tried to do exactly rather than linking to an external resource. Other than that good job on a first question!

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! Will keep that in mind the next time I post a question.
Fixed the problem! When I set up the container, I chose "Firebase" when I should have chosen "iOS(legacy)" (as I am using Google Analytics for the tags)

Comment: Could you please then answer the question below? It will help others struggling with a similar problem. Thank you

Comment: The question below? Do you mean the question about what I tried to do exactly?

Comment: You mentioned that you managed to fix the problem. It would be great if you could answer your own question on how you fixed it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the problem by creating a new container and choosing "iOS(Legacy)" instead of "Firebase". As I am using Google Tag Manager to access Google Analytics, I had to actually use the "iOS(Legacy)" setting.

Comment: I suppose you were using the GTM v3 with the container type "Firebase". If you're using the type "Firebase" for your container, you'll actually need the  latest GTM version, which is GTM v5. 
The type of the container doesn't change anything if you want to push events to Google Analytics, both types and both versions are able to do it.